# How do I define a FiniteSet in SymPy that compares elements by .equals()

Tags: python, sympy

When I define a FiniteSet like this:

```
FiniteSet(I*(-1.5 - sqrt(3)/2) + 1.5*I, I*(-sqrt(3)/2 - 0.5) + 0.5*I)
```

I get the resulting set

```
FiniteSet(I*(-1.5 - sqrt(3)/2) + 1.5*I, I*(-sqrt(3)/2 - 0.5) + 0.5*I)
```

this is somewhat wrong, as both Expressions simplify to -sqrt(3)*I/2. If I compare both Expressions with .equals(), it says True:

```
(I*(-1.5 - sqrt(3)/2) + 1.5*I).equals(I*(-sqrt(3)/2 - 0.5) + 0.5*I)==True
```

Is there a way to define a FiniteSet that compares Elements by .equals() instead of how they are defined by default?

Comment: A short remark: when working with sympy which is dedicated to exact symbolic calculations, it is very important to avoid floats. Expressions such as `1.5` and `0.5` should be replaced e.g. by `S(3)/2` and `S(1)/2`.  See [gotchas - python numbers vs sympy numbers](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers)

Comment: @JohanC the same happens when replacing the floats with fractions

Comment: What about `FiniteSet(simplify(I * (-3 - sqrt(3)) / 2 + 3 * I / 2), simplify(I * (-sqrt(3) - 1) / 2 + I / 2))`?

Comment: @JohanC that would work but it is very slow. expand is faster for this application

Comment: As you say, `simplify` is an expensive operation and so `FiniteSet` does not use it on its elements. You wouldn't expect `FiniteSet` to have to simplify a complicated integral just to realize that it does not cancel with anything. Most of the time, the added elements are unique. If you are worried about this kind of possibility, then it might be best to manually expand or simplify them before creating a `FiniteSet`.